# Detach and Append section depending on selected value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle, elementor

The current functionality I have is that when my page loads, the #all (CSS ID) element is displayed, and all other CSS ID's are hidden. When an option is selected from the dropdown, it hides all elements and displays only the selected one. The only problem is, the hidden elements are still registered in the DOM, which is quite high because of this. I've read about .detach and .append, but I'm struggling to get the same functionality.

I have tried tweaking my code with the .detach and .append jquery, but I'm not able to produce the results I would like.

**JS:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hideOnPageLoad').hide();
  $('#all').show();
  $('#DestinationSelect').change(function () {
    $('.hideOnPageLoad').hide();
    $selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $selectedValue).toggle();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```html
<select name="DestinationSelect" id="DestinationSelect">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a destination</option>
  <option value="all">View all destinations</option>
  <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="greece">Greece</option>
  <option value="iceland">Iceland</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="netherlands">The Netherlands</option>
  <option value="norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="switzerland">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="azores">The Azores</option>
  <option value="ski">Winter Skiing</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here.
The select Element will itself do the same thing and hide all the other values except for the default [Default Selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#basic_select).

Refer to the select element details from W3 - [Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)